# Assign colClasses to certain columns in data frames with unknown length

Tags: r

I have a number of data files that I am reading into R as CSVs. I would like to specify the colClasses of certain columns in these data files, but the lengths of the dataframes are unknown as they contain species abundance data (hence, different numbers of species).

Is there a way that I can set, say, every column after the first 10 to numeric (so, ncol[10]:length(df)) using colClasses in read.csv?

This is what I tried, but to no avail:

```
df <- read.csv("file.csv", header=T, colClasses=c(ncols[10], rep("numeric", ncols)))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: In such cases, I usually read the first line of the file and get the number of columns from there. If I have a header then I sometimes also use the column names to assign the classes. It would be interesting to see if there exists a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with using `count.fields` to determine how many columns there are in the data. You can do this just on the first line.

Then, from there, you can use `rep` for your `colClasses`.

It's fugly, but works. Here's an example:

The first few lines are just to create a dummy csv file in your workspace since you didn't provide a reproducible example.

```
X <- tempfile()
cat("A,B,C,D,E,F",
    "1,2,3,4,5,6",
    "6,5,4,3,2,1", sep = "\n", file = X)
```

This is where the actual answer starts. Replace "x" with your actual file name in both places below. The `-2` is because we have two columns that are already accounted for.

```
Y <- read.csv(X, colClasses = c(
  "numeric", "numeric", rep("character", count.fields(textConnection(
    readLines(X, n=1)), sep=",")-2)))

# Y <- read.csv("file.csv", colClasses = c(
#   "numeric", "numeric", rep(
#     "character", count.fields(readLines(
#       "file.csv", n = 1), sep = ",")-2)))

str(Y)
# 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ A: num  1 6
#  $ B: num  2 5
#  $ C: chr  "3" "4"
#  $ D: chr  "4" "3"
#  $ E: chr  "5" "2"
#  $ F: chr  "6" "1"
```